# simulating phone call in Android app for a wristband

Tags: android, android-vibration

I have an Android app that receives tasks from the server, but the environment that it will be used is noisy and vibration does not always work and the device is on user's belt. So I thought that I could use those "smart" wristbands that vibrate or glow and show caller id. Smart watches are too expensive for this so such wrist band would do it if I could simulate a phone call from my application.
Is there a way to create a call from an app on Android?

Comment: using the emulator you can simulate this using  `adb emu gsm` command line [more info](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#telephony)

Comment: Have you checked into those? There was a kickstarter that failed, and Jawbone's UP is $130. The Pebble is $150, but the price is going to come down once Samsung brings out their smart-watch. Additionally, you can program the pebble AND display essential information right on the watch.